# Domain is being used for spam - what to do?

Tags: spam, domain-name, email-bounces

I recently started to receive postmaster and mailerdaemon mails about undelivered mail that have been sent from my corporate domain. It's default spam: attached files/invoices/etc. and it's not coming from my server (we're using a paid email service provider). Most of the emails get rejected as spam as SPF is enabled on the domain, but I'm still worried some people get the mails or see them in the junk filter and associate my company with it.

I initially thought this would be a short attack and things would stop after 24-48 hours, but that has been 3 weeks ago and there are new waves of returned emails all the time which end up in my junk filter.

my SPF record:
`v=spf1 include:spf.messagingengine.com ?all`

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: What is your SPF record? What is your DMARC record?

Comment: Determine if it really is coming from your network or if the from address is just being spoofed. If its the latter, there's nothing much you can (assuming your SPF records are appropriately restrictive). If its the former, resign - nobody should be running an open relay in 2016.

Comment: From what I've seen, the FROM is spoofed; emails are sent mostly from Mexico. Added the SPF records as well.

Comment: I don't have a DMARC record though, what's that?

Comment: A DMARC Record is used to protect your company Image, if you set one up with a reject policy, and if the email that's pretending to come from you fails the DMARC Policy Check which includes (SPF and DKIM), it won't deliver the message. You can read more about it here: [DMARC](https://dmarc.org/) and you can generate the record with this [DMARC Wizard](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dmarcwizard/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Most of the emails get rejected as spam as SPF is enabled on the domain,

That is all you can do (enable SPF). At the end some postal admins are not too smart. A hard reject (SPF not allowed to send) should NEVER result in a reject message being sent.

> but I'm still worried some people get the mails or see them in the junk filter 
>   and associate my company with it.

You can bet some people still get those emails (if their email server is not using standard practices to filter out spam). But only very stupid or naive people would associate your company with it. Because - abusing other people email addresses is not exactly innovative. Happens daily. You are not the only one whose email addresses are abused.